# Having web.config sections copy to all configurations

Tags: .net, web-config

I have a section in my Web.config file that I want .NET to automatically copy to all the Web.config files in all my configurations (latest build, IAT, UAT, release etc).  What magical incantations can I type in my Web.config for that section file to make this happen?

Comment: How are your different config files per configuration setup in Visual Studio ?

Comment: oooh I'm not sure I understand what you mean Oded, but here is a section from my IAT config file.  Does this answer your question?  <configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

Comment: You are talking about config transforms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are asking how to ensure your linked configuration files (using `configSource` in `web.config`) are copied when deploying, ensure that their `Build Action` is set to `Content`.

You can set this by right-clicking the file in the Solution Explorer and selecting `Properties` (Alt + Enter).

---

Update:

Since you are talking about config transforms - these are only applied when you *deploy* a web project.

You can use the [slow cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) extension to get the transforms to apply on compilation.